# Setting variable data to morris.bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have to draw a bar chart with [Morris](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/), but data is dynamic in such a way that I don't know how many labels I am going to draw, etc...

Normally you build such a chart with:

```js
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar-example" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

But I don't know if I am having a and b, or a, b and c, or a, b, c and d or even more. How do I achieve this?

The data I am passing is a class that contains a label and a list of values, so I can draw multiple bars per label. The problem here is that I don't know how many bars I am drawing as the data is generated at runtime.

Edit:

I pass the data from the controller like this:

```
[{"label":"Cats","values":[57,92,94]},{"label":"Dogs","values":[85,78,53]},{"label":"Birds","values":[81,57,70]}]
```

So far I managed to draw the labels if I send them as an array of Strings, but if I send an array of 3 elements, it shows the first elements as they are but then adds three more "Undefined" labels.

With that data structure I get to see "Cats", "Dogs" and "Birds" on the x axis if I set:

```
xkey: 'label',
```

Comment: Do you need to create the graph the first time the page loads, or do you update the graph dynamically?

Comment: I create the graph the first time the page loads

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how you are passing this data from Java, do you send the serialized JSON data from a controller?

Comment: I added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my graph I don't think I quite captured what you are trying to display but hopefully it will get the wheels spinning. You can fetch the data via `ajax` and then create the chart on the fly by calling the function defined below as `createChart()`. I've made a dummy self-executing function that passes the data in you example:

```js
// dummy function to call createChart()
(function() {
  let data = `[
  { "label": "Cats", "values": [57, 92, 94] },
  { "label": "Dogs", "values": [85, 78, 53] },
  { "label": "Birds", "values": [81, 57, 70] }]`;
  createChart(data);
})();

function createChart(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  let labels = data.map(obj => obj.label);

  // Generte n keys
  let ykeys = data[0].values.map((obj, i) => 'val' + i);
  let values = data.map(function(obj) {
    let map = {
      label: obj.label
    }
    obj.values.forEach(function(obj, i) {
      map[ykeys[i]] = obj;
    });
    return map;
  });

  Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: values,
    xkey: 'label',
    ykeys: ykeys,
    labels: labels
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar-example" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Great, I adapted your code so I get the labels from the controller too, and it works :)